# Sideways cast without RTTI possible?

Tags: c++, c++17

In c++ if I have a diamond class hierarchy as follows:

```
       AbstractBaseClass
               /\
              /  \
  ConcreteClass AbstractBaseClassExtended
             \  /
              \/
           ConcreteClassTwo
```

Given a pointer to `AbstractBaseClassExtended` if I want to perform a sideways cast to `ConcreteClass` do I need to perform an upcast to `AbstractBaseClass` followed by a downcast to `ConcreteClass` using a sequence of two `dynamic_cast`s? If so, does this mean this can only be done in a program compiled with RTTI enabled and if I am working in an environment that disables RTTI that there is no way to do this?

Also, is it ever safe to use a `reinterpret_cast` to downcast from `AbstractBaseClassExtended` to `ConcreteClassTwo` or is that only guaranteed to be safe using a `dynamic_cast` and checking if it succeeded?

Comment: I believe you'd need `static_cast` rather than `reinterpret_cast` for downcasting and hope that it is valid. And you need just a single `dynamic_cast` to go to any point from any point in the diagram or any other scheme. `dynamic_cast` is very complex which is why it is relatively slow.

Comment: From reading the now deleted answer my current understanding is that a `static_cast` would be sufficient for both the upcast and the downcast but the downcast would potentially be unsafe.

Comment: Yup, no truly safe way to downcast without dynamic casting. It is generally advised to avoid usage of downcasting. There are only a couple of cases where it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Given your graph, i assume `ConcreteClass` and `AbstractBaseClassExtended` are both inheriting virtually from `AbstractBaseClass`.

**What is not possible:**

Going with the virtual inheritance assumption, it follows that given an `AbstractBaseClass` pointer the compiler can not know the addressoffset between the given pointer and any of the derived classes. The compiler doesnt know where to look for it statically.

So the route `AbstractBaseClassExtended`->`AbstractBaseClass`->`ConcreteClass` is not possible with `static_cast`.

**What is possible with static_cast:**

`AbstractBaseClassExtended` -> `ConcreteClassTwo` -> `ConcreteClass`

**Why is that possible:**

The classlayout for ConcreteClassTwo is fixed, so we are good to cast down statically ***IF WE CAN GUARANTEE*** that the `AbstractBaseClassExtended` pointer we are given is a `ConcreteClassTwo`. Once we have the `ConcreteClassTwo` pointer we can just static_cast/implicitly go up the hierachy to `ConcreteClass`. Again: it is important that you are sure you have a `ConcreteClassTwo` in reality, otherwise it is undefined behavior.

**How can dynamic_cast achieve it in just one cast:**

With rtti you may just do the crosscast in one cast. How can that work? `dynamic_cast` goes down the hierachy to the most derived type (the true dynamic runtime type of the given object) and then goes up the hierachy. If the upcast is unambiguous it will succeed.

**reinterpret_cast:**

reinterpret_cast is totally not the right tool at all to move in class hierachies, since it just reinterprets the pointer value with no further adjustments. avoid it at all costs.